# after image saving ,background color become black

Tags: image, image-processing, word-cloud

i use MVC and wordcloud nugget package.
i get a wordcloud on sample console application with white background , but get a wordcloud in mvc application with always black background. I dont have a knowledge about image class. I need your help thanks.
sample code :

```
 var wc = new WordCloudGen(1000, 600);
 Image y =wc.Draw(words, frequencies);
 y.Save(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\123.Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I thought it is because of the way i saved image object, but maybe it can be change in wordcloud project (i couldnt find it.) wordcloud project in nugget package manager: [wordcloud link](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wordcloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked through the code of WordCloud to see how it draws the background. It appears that it paints it with the *transparent* color. Everything is perfectly fine until you save your picture as jpeg. Since jpeg does not support transparency, your background color gets replaced with whatever comes its way.

The solution is pretty simple: use some format that supports transparency, for example PNG. Just replace your save line with

```
y.Save(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\123.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

and enjoy a nice picture with a transparent background. Modern browsers support png, so it shouldn't be a problem to use pictures in that format in your MVC application.